# Angular Error: [$injector:unpr] Filtering Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module

I've got an Angular app that's throwing me this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/unpr?p0=advFilterNameFilterProvider%20%3C-%20advFilterNameFilter
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:36:202
    at Object.c [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:36:270
    at Object.c [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at $get [as $filter] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:125:335)
    at gb.filter (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:172:465)
    at gb.filterChain (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:172:391)
    at gb.primary (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:169:270)
```

Based on the Angular Docs report of the error, I should be looking around for a missing provider. However, I can't seem to find what's missing. Here's my app file:

```
angular.module('programApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'programApp.controllers',
    'programApp.directives',
    'programApp.filters',
    'uiSwitch'
]).config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); 
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);;
```

Here's the top of my controller file:

```
angular.module('programApp.controllers', [])
.controller('programController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$location', 
                                  function($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout, $rootScope, $location){
```

I've also got 2 custom filters:

```
angular.module('programApp.filters', []).filter('filterName', function(){
//my filter code here
}).filter('advFilterName', function(){
//my other filter code here
});
```

And here's my one directive:

```
angular.module('programApp.directives', [])
.directive('ngEnter', function () {
//directive code here
});
```

Based on the error code and other SO questions, I think I should be looking into a provider issue with my filters... but I can't seem to find anything wrong there.

Also, none of my code is minified, so that's not the issue.

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-creating your module with each of your `angular.module` calls.

Leave out the `[]` from your `angular.module` calls when declaring your directives, filters, and controllers.

The standard 2-arg call to `angular.module`

```
angular.module('programApp', [])
```

is appropriate for **declaring** your module...but including the second argument (`[]`) in subsequent `angular.module` calls actually re-creates your module.

In other words, once you've declared your `prgoramApp' module, your filters should be declared like this

```
angular.module('programApp').filter('filterName', function(){
    //my filter code here
}).filter('advFilterName', function(){
    //my other filter code here
});
```

(without the `[]` in the call to `angular.module`)

See the [Creation vs Retrieval section of the Angular Module docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval) for more information on this.